# How to describe the Cartesian product $\mathbb{R} × \mathbb{R}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, terminology, real-numbers, direct-product

I am taking a discrete mathematics course in the spring and in an attempt to fully understand the material I am reading ahead. I came across this statement Let $\mathbb{R}$ denote the set of all real numbers. Describe $\mathbb{R} × \mathbb{R}$, and it got me thinking. I did not quite understand it at first until I saw the answer and re-read it a few times. For me the ah-ha moment was after reading it a second time and seeing the answer. So I included the answer to share with the community because maybe someone else out there could benefit in the same way I did when I saw the answer.

After completing my research on this site on how to describe a Cartesian Product of the form $\mathbb{R} × \mathbb{R}$, I was only able to come up with descriptions that a.) did not apply directly to what I was looking for and b.) were over-complicated in there response.

So again if $\mathbb{R}$ is said to denote the set of all real numbers. Describe $\mathbb{R} × \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: What exactly do you find unsatisfying about the definition?

Answer (score 4):

**Formal Defintion:**

Given sets $A$ and $B$, the Cartesian product of $A$ and $B$, denoted $A × B$ and read
“$A\: \mbox{cross} \: B$,” is the set of all ordered pairs $(a, b)$, where $a$ is in $A$ and $b$ is in $B$.
Symbolically:
$A × B = \left\{(a, b) \: |  \:a \: \in \: A \: \mbox{and} \: b \in B\right\}$

**Thus we have:**

$\mathbb{R} × \mathbb{R}$ is the set of all ordered pairs $(x, y)$ where both $x$ and $y$ are real numbers. If horizontal and vertical axes are drawn on a plane and a unit length is marked off, then each ordered pair in $\mathbb{R} × \mathbb{R}$ corresponds to a unique point in the plane, with the first and second elements of the pair indicating, respectively, the horizontal and vertical positions of the point.

[image]

The term Cartesian plane is often used to refer to a plane with
this coordinate system.

Image and source Credit: Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications, 4th Edition, Epp

Comment: Provide formal accepted definition as well.

Comment: Added formal definition.

Comment: An equivalent definition that I find easier to work with: $$\forall x,y:[ (x,y)\in \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\iff x\in\mathbb{R}\land y\in\mathbb{R}]$$